# What are the earliest references to Jesus' birthday being December 25?

Tags: origin, christmas

One of the arguments in favor of the traditional date of December 25 being the actual date of Jesus birth is that of church tradition.

Of course, it's possible that the early church just picked a date connected with the winter solstice to celebrate the birthday of Jesus. The scholar Ray Butterworth points out how the Queen's Birthday, is celebrated on the second Saturday in June in the UK, and the Monday before May 25 in Canada, regardless of her actual birthday.

However, it is plausible (perhaps even probable) that Mary, the mother of Jesus, might have spoken to the disciples in the early faith communities about the specific symmetrical period and days of Jesus' conception and birth.

While one might argue that was improbable that there was a perfect symmetrical time of 9 months between the conception of Jesus and his birth, C.S. Lewis made a compelling observation:

> You must develop a nose like a bloodhound for those steps in the
> argument which depend not on historical and linguistic knowledge but
> on the concealed assumption that miracles are impossible, improbable,
> or improper. And this means that you must really re-educate yourself:
> must work hard and consistently to eradicate from your mind the whole
> type of thought in which we have all been brought up. (Miracles)

A good discussion on stackexchange on the matter of whether it was appropriate for Jews to celebrate birthdays can be found [here.](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/74389/did-jesus-disciples-celebrate-his-birthday) The quote from Rabbi Mendy Kaminker, in support of Jews celebrating birthdays, is particularly relevant.

The first century philosopher Plutarch writes:

> ...they are those that tell us that, as the Greeks are used to
> allegorize Kronos (or Saturn) into chronos (time), …

Lucian of Samosata (AD 120-180) describes the festivities of *Saturnalia/Chronos*, as seven day event. Marcus Valerius Martialis in his also speaks of the *Saturnalia* being a seven day event (Epigrams, 72, Book XIV). These authors wrote prior to when the *Sol Invictus* was highlighted and celebrated as a Roman holiday in the fourth century.

Changes to the Roman calendar moved the climax of *Saturnalia/Chronos* to December 25th, around the time of the date of the winter solstice.

So, if December 25th was the birthday of Jesus that Mary shared with the disciples, it may very likely be a type of double entendre when the Apostle Paul writes:

> ...when the fullness of time (chronos) had come, God sent forth his Son,
> born of woman, born under the law, to redeem those who were under the
> law,... (Galatians 4)

In other words, the primal origins of Christmas can be found in a rebranding of *Saturnalia/Chronos* in line with longings of a mythical golden age coming in Jesus in terms of both time (*chronos*) and spatial (literal) history.

In scanning the internet I have come across multiple references to Theophilus (A.D. 115-181), bishop of Caesarea in Palestine:

> We ought to celebrate the birthday of Our Lord on what day soever the
> 25th of December shall happen. - Magdeburgenses, Cent. 2. c. 6.
> Hospinian, De origine Festorum Chirstianorum.

The problem is that I can't find the original source for this quote. Has it been lost in history? If so, what are some plausible reasons on how this might have happened? In researching the background to the quote from Theophilus, the evidence so far indicates that this quote seems to be based on a fictional account created in Ireland around 600 AD. For example, see this [recent research](https://www.roger-pearse.com/weblog/2021/12/28/did-theophilus-of-caesarea-in-196-ad-state-that-christmas-must-be-observed/) by Roger Pearse.

In another line of tradition, McClellan notes that Chrysostom around 407 A.D. (Hom. in diem, natal, ii Col. 351) writes:

> It is not yet ten years since this day (December 25) was made known.
> Even so, it is now just as seriously observed as if it has come to us
> form the the beginning...It is very plain, according to the
> evangelist, that Christ was born during the first census, and in Rome
> it is possible for any one to deduce, with the aid of the public
> archives, when this came about. From persons who have an intimate
> knowledge of the records and who still live there and who have kept
> the day in accordance with an age long tradition have recently given
> us this information. (McClellan, p. 407)

Could a large section of the church in those days have forgotten the date of Jesus' birth so easily? If so what are some plausible explanations? Was Chrysostom somewhat limited in his information from other areas? For example, he writes in another place that the charismatic gifts ceased. Yet, other church fathers attest to their continuance.

An argument for Clement (150–215 AD) of Alexandria (Stromateis 1.21.145) saying that some hold to December 25th as Jesus' birthday can be found [here.](http://www.dec25th.info/Loosing%20the%20Riddle%20of%20Clement%20Alexandria%27s%20Dates%20for%20the%20Nativity,%20Baptism,%20Passion,%20and%20Epiphany%20of%20Christ.html)

The author argues that Clement's 25th day of Pachon should be interpreted along the lines how, "When viewed through the prism of the Athenian calendar, we find that the traditional date of December 25 comes forth quite naturally."

Another site, [here](https://www.themoorings.org/Jesus/birth/date.html#January), argues that Clement held to January 6th as the birthdate of Jesus:

> Can we pinpoint the date of Jesus' birth? Various ancient sources lead
> us to the answer. Clement of Alexandria (again, about AD 200) says,
> "From the birth of Christ, therefore, to the death of Commodus ...are, in all, a hundred
> and ninety-four years, one month, thirteen days." If we suppose that
> he is using the Roman calendar, we deduce that Clement set Christ's
> birth on 18 November 3 BC. But it is highly doubtful that this date,
> affirmed by no other ancient source, is the one he so confidently
> espouses. We arrive at a different date if we suppose that Clement, a
> resident of Egypt, is using the Egyptian calendar without
> intercalation. Measuring backward from Commodus' death an interval of
> 194 years (each exactly 365 days), one month (thirty days), and
> thirteen days brings us to 6 January 2 BC.

There is also a mentioning of the December 25th by Hippolytus in his commentary on Daniel (dated 202 A.D.). The quote itself, along with a textual critical approach on the reliability of this reference, can be found [here.](http://www.dec25th.info/Textual%20Tradition%20of%20Hippolytus%20Commentary%20on%20Daniel.html)

The total references, included above, push the earliest testimony of the church fathers to the date of Jesus birth on December 25th to the late 2nd century and early 3rd century.

A related question can be found here: [What is the earliest historical testimony of the celebration of the nativity of the Lord Jesus Christ?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/45948/what-is-the-earliest-historical-testimony-of-the-celebration-of-the-nativity-of/45949)

Comment: Related https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/5144/23657

Comment: [CATHOLIC ENCYCLOPEDIA: Christmas](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/03724b.htm) might be of some use, as it lists many references to the date of birth on many different dates.  Note this though: "*The well-known solar feast, however, of Natalis Invicti, celebrated on 25 December, has a strong claim on the responsibility for our December date.*".

Comment: Ray, I don’t know about that. If the “Natalia Invicti” was celebrated on December 25th, in the first century, it would be a providential coincidence. It would be kind of like the eruption of Mount Vesuvius. Did it happen, providentially, at the same time as Vulcanalia (August 23) or not? The latest evidence seems to indicate a later date.

Comment: @Jess, the Catholic Encyclopedia isn't saying it was a random coincidence.  It is saying that the Church chose an official date, and their choice was influenced by the existing celebrations on December 25. I.e. they don't claim that December 25 was the actual birth date, only that it is the official date on which the birth is celebrated. ¶ Compare with the Queen's Birthday, which is celebrated on the second Saturday in June in the UK, and the Monday before May 25 in Canada, regardless of her actual birthday.

Comment: Ray, I see your point. It’s a pious way of celebrating December 25th as the birthday of Jesus without actually believing it literally was on that day. I just think it’s likely that Jesus actually was born on that day.

Comment: Ray, even if I’m wrong, I’m thinking the winter solstice would have been the primary reason for picking that day & not because a popular pagan celebration was going on at the time that the Christians wanted to compete with.

Comment: The choice of December 25 for Christmas has nothing to do with pagan festivals. https://historyforatheists.com/2020/12/pagan-christmas/

Comment: @Jess I'm pretty sure it wasn't. IIRC, wasn't Jesus was born during Passover, which is during the Spring? I know He also died during Passover, since the Last Supper was a Passover feast.

Comment: I'm trying to hunt down the Theophilus quote.  It's embedded in a Lutheran church history [Magdeburg Centuries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magdeburg_Centuries) published 1559-1574 [**page scan here**](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=yale.39002006888532&view=1up&seq=17), chief editor [Matthias Flacius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthias_Flacius).  Which in turn was quoted by a Reformed theologian [Rudolf Hospinian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudolf_Hospinian) in his work *De festia Judæorum et Ethnicorum ... festorum dierum Christianorum* published 1592-93.

Comment: [The only undoubted extant work of Theophilus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theophilus_of_Antioch#Editions) is his [Apology to Autolycus](https://www.newadvent.org/fathers/0204.htm), [Greek text here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=iQURAAAAYAAJ&redir_esc=y), Volume 6 of the famous 161 volumes [Patrologia Graeca](https://patristica.net/graeca/) published in [mid 19th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrologia_Graeca), not all translated yet to English.  Unfortunately, the quote doesn't seem to be there, so the search continues ... :-(

Comment: Here's Google page scan of the [2nd volume of Centuriae Magdeburgenses at page 126](https://books.google.ca/books?id=NTs-AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA126#v=onepage&q&f=false) where the most relevant section is: *De Festis Christianorvm, Ac Primvm de Paschate* ("On the Feasts of Christians and on the First Passover") (1.5 pages).  Page heading "Cent. II. CAP VI."  Several mentions of Theophilus on pg 127, but not exactly the same quote.  Found more contexts of the quote [here](https://truthsaves.org/articles/is-christmas-a-pagan-holiday/) and [here](http://www.sdadefend.com/Standards/christmas-3.htm).

Comment: GD, great work! Now, if somebody can run those Latin words through Goggle translation that would be most helpful.

Comment: @Jess What makes me very curious is where the Magdeburgenses author got the quote from?  Since it was already in Latin, it should have been available to medieval scholars instead of coming from the new Greek texts flowing from the end of the Byzantine empire during the Renaissance.   If so, we could have other books embedding the quote, maybe Peter Lombard sentences or other *medieval* collection of Patristic quotes?

Comment: GD, good point. They really need to digitize all the books so that it is easier to find references. There are also lots of lost books over the years. One such document was a five volume series produced by a church father Papias on the sayings of Jesus. Apparently the full text may have survived as late as the middle ages in Europe, as one library has it listed as being in their collection.

Comment: According to the [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weihnachten), the first document saying that Jesus was born 25th of December was [the Chronograph of 354](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronograph_of_354). However, it is not sure if the 25th of December was selected as date for Christmas because it was a public holiday in Rome or because it is believed that Mary's pregnancy began at 25th of march. 25th of December would be *exactly* 9 months later. However, in both cases it would be improbable that 25th of December is the actual birthday.

Comment: Martin, there is a providential possibility that there was a nice perfect symmetry of 9 months between the conception of Jesus and his birth. If so, it would be  something that Mary, the mother of Jesus, would have noted and commented upon in oral conversations with the faith community. 

I follow what C.S. Lewis once said, "You must develop a nose like a bloodhound for those steps in the argument which depend not on historical and linguistic knowledge but on the concealed assumption that miracles are impossible, improbable, or improper."

Comment: Martin, I made some changes based upon your comments. I once thought that finding a symmetry of 9 months between the conception of Jesus and his birth was a good indication that a December 25th birth was probably a made up date. Now, I'm not so sure of that line of reasoning.

Comment: There is an equally probable line of reasoning (from the data we have) that Jesus was conceived on the Festival of Lights and born at the commencement of the Feast of Tabernacles when the Word became flesh and "tabernacled" among us.